# Stop a find-in-file search in Visual Studio 2013 which is taking forever

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I just searched my entire solution for a certain string which apparently exists in many minified JavaScript files. This causes the Visual Studio process to pretty much hang while it outputs the content of those minified files in the Find Result window, because they're up to several megabytes in size.

Is there any way to stop this process once it's started?

Comment: Apart from the built-in stop command? No. Kill VS via task manager and restart it if you have to.

Answer (score 2):

There is a stop button in VS 'Find Results' window.
Usually it has red cross icon

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work in the scenario I described, because the application window hangs and can't respond to clicks and such.

Answer (score 2):

**Ctrl+Break** should stop the search.

Comment: I thought it did, so I accepted the answer, but now it seems I was just lucky. It doesn't work.