# Stop Visual Studio 2015 form continuing on a search on solution

Tags: visual-studio

Let's say I have pressed Ctrl+Shift+F and have started a search for "Something" in Vs 2015. Then I figure I don't want it to go on. 
Which keyboard short keys are suggested for this purpose? I have seen links on web like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2007/11/09/did-you-know-how-to-stop-a-find-in-files-search.aspx) but it is for older versions of VS.

Comment: It is `Edit.StopSearch` command, for which you can assign your own shortcut in keyboard settings. By default, it is `Alt+F3, S`, as stated in the answer below.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360222/stop-a-find-in-file-search-in-visual-studio-2013-which-is-taking-forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Find Results window, you can click on the 'X' mark at the end to Stop your search in Visual Studio 2015.

Please find below the screenshot & the corresponding keyboard shortcut --

[image]

Comment: Clicking the button does the trick, but pressing Alt + F3,S does not work for me Alt + S worked for me, though, because I am using ReSharper.